C# Console converts tabs to spaces
If I print string such:
Console.WriteLine(@"test1\ttest2\ttest3")

and try to copy the output to excel it will all be in one column, because the Console prints tabs as spaces, is it possible to make it use tabs ?
update: Sorry i meant:
Console.WriteLine("test1\ttest2\ttest3")

Removing @ does not make any difference on my system (Widows 11)

I would doubt that you get consistent behavior here on different systems. Console behavior might differ or even that Excel interprets a Tab as column separator might be dependent on regional settings. If you need control over how things end up in an Excel sheet consider talking to Excel directly or create a proper file in a format Excel knows.

even with your edit, which makes more sense there isn't really a solution which would work for all terminal client/command prompt windows you name it - each could differ in how it displays tabs, copies tabs... you should consider a different route to take

Firstly:
@"test1\ttest2\ttest3

contains no tab characters: literal strings (@ prefix) do not make use of character escapes. I am going to assume the use of a literal string here was a typo and you meant to write:
Console.WriteLine("test1\ttest2\ttest3");

otherwise this Q makes no sense.
Summary: this is not about C# or .NET, it is about how consoles process control characters into screen output. The C equivalent printf("test1\ttest2\ttest3"); would give the same result.
The tab control character moves the output position (cursor) to the next tab stop and continues writing text from that point. Depending on the console you maybe able to control where the tab stops are positioned (eg. using these control sequences).
When copying to the clipboard from a console, typically unwritten character cells (eg. skipped by moving to the next tab stop) are copied as spaces.
Because tab is a control character it is not written to the console as text, instead it is processed to control cursor position. Once the output is written there is no longer a control character to copy.

It is possible to make it use tabs.
The "@" character at the start of the string tells the compiler to interpret the string literally. This means  \t is treated as two separate characters (\ and t) instead of a tab character.
If you want \t to be interpreted as a tab character, you should remove the @ character. Here's how you can do it:
In this case, \t will be interpreted as a tab character, and when you copy the output to Excel, each test will be in a separate column.
If you want to use include a tab character in a verbatim string literal (the one that starts with @) You can do so by inserting tab in your code.
Adding an image that shows this:


this statement and when you copy the output to Excel, each test will be in a separate column. isn't universally true, it depends how the copy command treats the tab, as was pointed out in the other answer it could be treated as space see for example here: https://i.sstatic.net/AOPcy98J.png - where I activated show all characters in notepad++

and thats the issue op seems to be facing (though OPs code sample was wrong) copying data from the command prompt results in spaces and not tabs

"Here's how you can do it:" looks a bit strange. I expect something after the colon, but there is nothing.

You're absolutely right @rand-random. The behavior of copying and pasting tab-separated values can vary. Your point is well taken and it's an important detail to consider when working with tab-separated values. For op, you might want to consider using a different format, like CSV (comma-separated values), which is more widely supported.
